# Filewriter and spaces?

Tags: java, filewriter

I was asked to write an assignment wherein the user would be prompted to input a key and/or a value.

So far, here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class bTree
{
    //Fields


    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    static boolean done = false;

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter("data.txt");
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter command: ");
            String enter[] = input.nextLine().split(" ", 3);

            if(enter[0].toLowerCase().equals("insert"))
            {

                fWriter.write(enter[1] + "\n" + enter[2] + "\n");
                fWriter.flush();
            }
            else if(enter[0].toLowerCase().equals("select"))
            {
                FileReader fReader = new FileReader("data.txt");
                Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(fReader);

                while(fileInput.hasNext() && done == false)
                {
                    if(fileInput.nextLine().equals(enter[1]))
                    {
                        System.out.println(fileInput.nextLine());
                        done = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fileInput.nextLine();
                    }
                }
                done = false;
            }
            else if(enter[0].toLowerCase().equals("update"))
            {

                fWriter.write(enter[2]);
                fWriter.flush();
            }
            else if(enter[0].toLowerCase().equals("exit"))
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        while(true);
    }
}
```

Problem: When i open the data.txt, there are no spaces. So if i enter "insert 1001 gen" and "10001 genny", in notepad, it would come out as "1001gen10001genny". Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure that you don't run that program in a Turkish locale. A user that inputs `EXIT` there will not be able to exit your program. Instead of `toLowerCase` you should either use `equalsIgnoreCase` or just expect your users to always type lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `notepad.exe` is picky about line endings, and there are many possibilities. When you write `"\n"` to a `FileWriter`, it writes a single character, namely `'\n'`. But notepad expects the sequence `"\r\n"` instead. It shows a single `"\n"` as *nothing*.

Here is your code, slightly modified to work around some pitfalls.

```
package so7696816;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Excercise {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    PrintWriter fWriter = new PrintWriter("data.txt");

    while (true) {
      System.out.print("Enter command: ");
      String enter[] = input.nextLine().split(" ", 3);
      final String command = enter[0].toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);

      if (command.equals("insert")) {
        fWriter.println(enter[1]);
        fWriter.println(enter[2]);
        fWriter.flush();

      } else if (command.equals("select")) {
        FileReader fReader = new FileReader("data.txt");
        Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(fReader);
        while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
          String key = fileInput.nextLine();
          String value = fileInput.nextLine();
          if (key.equals(enter[1])) {
            System.out.println(value);
            break;
          }
        }
        fReader.close(); // don't leave files open

      } else if (command.equals("update")) {
        fWriter.write(enter[2]);
        fWriter.flush();

      } else if (command.equals("exit")) {
        return;

      } else {
        System.err.println("Unknown command: " + command);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Remarks:

- I used a `PrintWriter` instead of a `FileWriter` to get the line endings correct.
- For the `select` command I closed the `fReader` after using it.
- I avoided to type `enter[0].toLowerCase()` multiple times.
- I used the proper variant of `toLowerCase`.
- I added error handling for unknown commands.
- I rewrote the `select` command to be a little more concise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `String enter[] = input.nextLine().split(" ", 3);`, it kills the Spaces. So append a space after each array entry or write an additional " " everytime you use `fWriter.write`.

[look here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

As already stated the line feed character is incorrect for notepad. Alternatively you could wrap that FileWriter in a BufferedWriter and use the newLine method to always insert the correct line feed.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are running your program in UNIX. In unix system "\r\n" is the line feed.

If you are running your program in Windows, I think the file should contain something like this.

1001

gen

10001

genny

Comment: On Unix systems the usual line ending is simply `\n`. On Windows systems it is `\r\n`, and on traditional MacOS it is `\r`.